# Azure Terraform Hub and Spoke with multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

i would like to deploy Azure landingzone using terraform in multiple subscriptions, Hub network should have azure firewall in subscription1 and each spoke have different subscriptions, i need 4 spokes which would be deployed in 4 separate subscriptions.

can some one help me with logic, how to write terraform.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirements, here is the [architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke) that you can follow. The Hub and the spoke are connected via the VNet [Peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview). According to the description:

> The virtual networks can be in the same, or different subscriptions.
> When you peer virtual networks in different subscriptions, both
> subscriptions can be associated to the same or different Azure Active
> Directory tenant.

So you can peer VNets in two different subscriptions. I assume you use the Azure CLI as the authentication your account already login and has enough permission in both two subscriptions. Here is an example code:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  alias = "subscription1"

  subscription_id = "xxxxxxx"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  alias = "subscription2"

  subscription_id = "xxxxxxx"
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "remote" {
  provider = azurerm.subscription1
  name = "remote_vnet_name"
  resource_group_name = "remote_group_name"
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  provider = azurerm.subscription2
  name = "vnet_name"
  resource_group_name = "group_name"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "peering" {
  provider = azurerm.subscription2
  name                         = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}-to-${data.azurerm_virtual_network.remote.name}"
  resource_group_name          = "group_name"
  virtual_network_name         = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  remote_virtual_network_id    = data.azurerm_virtual_network.remote.id
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic      = true

  # `allow_gateway_transit` must be set to false for vnet Global Peering
  allow_gateway_transit = false
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "peering1" {
  provider = azurerm.subscription1
  name                         = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.remote.name}-to-${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
  resource_group_name          = "remote_group_name"
  virtual_network_name         = data.azurerm_virtual_network.remote.name
  remote_virtual_network_id    = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic      = true

  # `allow_gateway_transit` must be set to false for vnet Global Peering
  allow_gateway_transit = false
}
```

The VNet peering always comes with a pair. So you need to create a peering for each VNet that in the different subscriptions in a peering. This example just shows you how to create a peering for the two VNets in different subscriptions. Then you can complete the whole architecture as you wish in Terraform.

Comment: Yeah, this is good charles. but i would like to deploy this terraform template via azure devops pipeline. in that case how to manage subscriptions?

Comment: @G.Prashanth I think it's the same way.

Comment: i am getting authentication errors charles, when i follow the same way.

Comment: @G.Prashanth What error do you get? permission denied?

Comment: Hi Charles, i am getting message as "error occurred" message that's it. i am not getting specific error message, getting error with terraform plan in azure devops pipeline.

Comment: @G.Prashanth Were you able to achieve using azure devops ? Could you please share the approach? Thank you.